# Python - format datetime with timezone

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a datetime with timezone field in my model in Django defined like this:

`created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

It is stored in database like this: `2022-08-12 09:41:13.815705+02`

I have added a property on that model to display custom formatted datetime:

```
@property
def created_date(self):
    date_obj = self.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return date_obj
```

It is now displayed like this: `2022-08-12 07:41:13`

The problem is the two hours time difference between stored time and displayed time. Time is stored in Central European Summer Time (+2). I want the displayed time to display "9:41:13" instead of "7:41:13". It needs to be corrected to users timezone. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you try fixing it by calling `self.created_at.astimezone().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`? I think `astimezone()` should fix that problem, but I'm not really sure about that. For me it was working.

Answer (score 1):

Im using:

```
@property
def created_date(self):
    date_obj = (timezone.localtime(self.created_at)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return date_obj
```

But this is only for some in python buisness logic, and pdf/xls raports. in template you just use `mymodel.created_at` its automatycly localize.

PS. I don't know if it's the right way to go because my apps(for now :)) lives in one timezone.

Comment: I tried that and it works but I also had to change in my settings.py TIME_ZONE = 'CET'. Default was UTC. My app also lives in one time zone so it should be ok.